# 404 Error with Static Files served through Django/Apache (Bitnami)

Tags: python, django, apache, amazon-ec2

I'm receiving 404 errors when trying to access static files on my django app in production on EC2, although it was staged in the same Bitnami stack in a Vbox absolutely fine. My `Alias` entries in `httpd.conf` work fine for `robots.txt` and `favicon.ico` - I can access them correctly. I cannot however appear to access anything specific in `/static` using it's `Alias` entry (i.e. on all pages).

I'm getting NO errors in my apache logs regarding being blocked by server configs/etc, and the permissions on my `static` folder are (temporarily) set to 777 and it doesn't help. What am I doing wrong?

My STATIC_ROOT is `/opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/data_dashboard/project/static`

My `httpd.conf` file looks like this:

```
<Directory /opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/data_dashboard/project/project>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/data_dashboard/project/project/wsgi.py

<Directory "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/data_dashboard/project/static">
    Require all granted
</Directory>


Alias /static /opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/data_dashboard/project/static
Alias /robots.txt /opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/data_dashboard/project/static/robots.txt
Alias /favicon.ico /opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/data_dashboard/project/static/favicon.ico
```

My `httpd-vhosts.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com

Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/data_dashboard/project/conf/httpd-app.conf"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/data_dashboard/project/conf/certs/server.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/data_dashboard/project/conf/certs/server.key"

Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/data_dashboard/project/conf/httpd-app.conf"
```

My `http-app.conf`:

```
<IfDefine !IS_DJANGOSTACK_LOADED> 
Define IS_DJANGOSTACK_LOADED
WSGIDaemonProcess wsgi-djangostack   processes=2 threads=15    display-name=%{GROUP}
</IfDefine> 

<Directory     "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/data_dashboard/project/project">
Options +MultiViews
AllowOverride All
<IfVersion < 2.3 >
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</IfVersion>
<IfVersion >= 2.3>
    Require all granted
</IfVersion>

WSGIProcessGroup wsgi-djangostack

WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
<IfVersion < 2.3 >
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</IfVersion>
<IfVersion >= 2.3>
    Require all granted
</IfVersion>

</Directory>



<Directory "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django">
Options +MultiViews
AllowOverride All
<IfVersion < 2.3 >
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</IfVersion>
<IfVersion >= 2.3>
    Require all granted
</IfVersion>

</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this, although not by figuring out the exact problem unfortunately. I created a blank EC2 server with the same stack, took the Apache conf files from all levels and added in the parameters which I believed were added. So started the conf from scratch effectively.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation (https://wiki.bitnami.com/BitNami_Cloud_Hosting/Base_stack), it seems like Amazon EC2 uses Apache version 2.2.29. You should change `httpd.conf` to cover both that version and the one in your other setup

```
<Directory /opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/data_dashboard/project/static>
    <IfVersion < 2.3 >
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.3>
        Require all granted
    </IfVersion>
</Directory>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Unfortunately my stack is using 2.4.12. I've tried this anyway for clarity and the same problem persists.